Query by date returns completed with empty output
I have a spreadsheet with a sheet that sorts the data by name. This is not a public accessible spreadsheet.  On a second spreadsheet I import the results as follows:
query(importrange("xxxxx-6BBA","'Responses'!AD:AK")," select * where Col1 is not null  offset 2",0)

This works fine and imports all of the data sorted by name. Each entry also has a date column (eg Aug 5, 2024)
I would like a second sheet that also imports the same data, but only shows dates greater than today. (so sheet 1 is all the data sorted by name and sheet 2 is all the data sorted by name but only those with a date after today) Here is the code I tried:
query(importrange("xxxxx-6BBA","'Responses'!AD:AK")," select * where Col1 is not null and Col7 > date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'  offset 2",0)

All I get is a result of N/A with message of query completed with empty output. But a date like Aug 5, 2024 is after today and should show in the results.  What am I doing wrong?
Thanks,
Doc

This sounds like a data type issue - when column 7 is coming over on the import, it's not being assigned as a date, causing the date query to fail. Is there a mix of data (dates/numbers/strings) in that column? Can you assign date formatting to that column in the source file?

First question, column 7 are all dates, like Aug 6, 2024.  I changed column 7 format on the first sheet where imported from to date.  Still no go.  If Col7 data type is the issue, how do I change it and be sure it is correct (other than what I did).  In other words you said can I assign date formatting to that column in the source file. Is there another way to do that?

Don't know if this helps, but as a double check, went to sheet importing from, took column AJ3 which has value of May 30, 2024 and went to a blank cell with =isdate(AJ3) and comes back true.

I found a simple workaround to the issue. There were 8 columns in the worksheet with Col7 (the one being imported). I created a new column with  =arrayformula(datevalue(AJ1:AJ))  and changed the query with the importrange to use Col9 instead of Col7, and it worked fine.  It was an easy fix rather then searching through everything to find the data discrepancy.
